# Train to be a Texas Hold'em dealer

Tags: gratis, web-apps, game

Our school is having a casino night with one of the tables being Texas Hold'em.
I have volunteered to be a dealer for Texas Hold'em and need to practice as a dealer so as not to make mistakes.

So I just need a program that lets me train as a Texas Hold'em dealer.

It would be really nice if the program had the players make incorrect bets, ask what the button are for, what are the sequence of winning hands, have players argue over who won so that the dealer can clearly show who won, have the dealer burn cards, etc. I have played thousands of games on XBOX but have never been the dealer.

Comment: On what OS should it run? And how much money would you be willing to spend if it comes to paid solutions?

Comment: Of interest: SE: Poker - Questions tagged: [Texas Hold'em, rules](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texas-hold-em+rules?page=1&sort=newest&pagesize=50)

Comment: Of interest: [2013 World Series of Poker Official Dealer Guide](https://www.wsop.com/2013/2013_WSOP_Dealer_Guide.pdf)

Comment: I think you can try the regular online versions of this game to practice. Visit [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hoh_zPVZZkg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hoh_zPVZZkg) to find out about the platform on which you can do this.